# how can I give a variable another value inside a function in python?

Tags: python, wordpress, loops, if-statement, xml-rpc

I'm creating a simple python script that checks for new comments on a WordPress blog using the xmlrpc API.

I'm stuck with a loop that should tell me if there are new comments or not. Here's the code:

```
def checkComm():
    old_commCount = 0;
    server = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(server_uri); # connect to WP server
    comments = server.wp.getComments(blog_id, server_admin, admin_pass, filters);
    new_commCount = len(comments);
    if new_commCount > old_commCount:
        print "there are new comments"
        old_commCount = new_commCount
    else:
        print "no new comments"

while True:
    checkComm()
    time.sleep(60)
```

I've skipped the variables like blog_id, server_admin etc.. since they add nothing to this question.

Can you tell what is wrong with my code?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'stuck'? What is going on with your code?

Comment: You don't need semicolons in Python. They don't harm your code, but they aren't necessary, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to pass it as a parameter, because you are resetting it every time you call the function:

```
def checkComm(old_commCount): # passed as a parameter
    server = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(server_uri) # connect to WP server
    comments = server.wp.getComments(blog_id, server_admin, admin_pass, filters)
    new_commCount = len(comments)
    if new_commCount > old_commCount:
        print "there are new comments"
        old_commCount = new_commCount
        return old_commCount # return it so you can update it
    else:
        print "no new comments"
        return old_commCount

comm_count = 0 # initialize it here
while True:
    comm_count = checkComm(comm_count) # update it every time
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: I've solved thanks to your suggestion but not using your actual code.
I had to take `old_commCount = new_commCount`
`return old_commCount`
outside of the if/else statement. The way you wrote it if the else statement was true the old_commCount was getting the Null value.
This way it always get updated and returned, even if there are no new comments.

I'll post the complete code as soon as I'll be allowed to (low rep)

Thanks again

Comment: @danix No problem. Not sure what you meant by the Null value (`None`?)... Don't see why it would do that, but glad to help :)

Comment: I'm checking again your solution and now the issue is not coming up.. sorry for the noise, your solution is perfectly working.. thanks again..